# How to restore to window mode when minimized in qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt

```
void test()
{
    if(flag==1)
    {
        qDebug("in if");
        showNormal();
        flag=0;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug("in else");
        showMinimized();
        flag=1;
    }
}
```

I use a `QTimer` to connect this function.
I want it run as this: minimized, sleep 3sec, restore to window mode, sleep 3 sec, minimized....

But the actual result is minimized, sleep 3, do nothing, sleep 3, do nothing, sleep 3, restore to window mode. After minimized, there are two times the function do nothing. How this can happened, and how to fix it?

Comment: The question is so vague. It'd be better if you provide more of your code

Comment: it's a very simple program,a window with a button. when your start there code, the function "testslots" will run every 3 seconds. i want the window minimized,the restore,then minimized,then restore. (my purpose is to test how to restore the mainwindow when it in minimized mode).here is the code:   https://github.com/iverhan/test.git

Comment: I've cloned your code from [github](https://github.com/iverhan/test.git) and it works as expected for me.  I added some extra `qDebug` statements to make sure everything was getting called at the correct intervals and it all looks fine.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming your widget is w, then try

```
w->setWindowState(w->windowState() & ~Qt::WindowMinimized | Qt::WindowActive);
```

to restore the window, and

```
w->setWindowState(w->windowState() | Qt::WindowMinimized)
```

to show the window minimised. You should post more of your code so that we can better understand the problem.

Comment: I couldn't find this answer anywhere else. This actually restores the normal or maximized state correctly. Thanks!